# Why does Google Colab say I have too many sessions?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run two notebooks on Google Colab but could only connect one notebook at a time to the virtual machine. There's a pop-up message saying "Too many sessions. You have too many active sessions. Terminate an existing session to continue." when I click the "connect" button on the second notebook. Does anybody know why?

Screenshot:

[image]

Edit: I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 10

Edit March 3, 2020: I ended up not using Colab that day, but I came back the next day and was able to run two Colab notebooks just fine. strange. I had this issue a couple of times since I posted this question, but the error disappeared the following day.

Comment: Hi Damilola, thanks for your input. I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 10. The notebook I'm running is Colab Notebook. The full screenshot would not tell any additional information than the error box. Best,

Comment: I have the same issue, one at a time!! Mange session also shows only one active notebook! This is strange! only one!!?!?!?!

Comment: I'm also facing the same thing. I can only run one session at a time in Colab Pro.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and I found my solution in [this issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2163#issuecomment-890663112). I change the **Runtime Shape** to **Standard** in the 2nd notebook, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am used to use it with 2 active sessions. I mean, it gives that error when I try to connect for the third notebook. Today, however, I could only connect 1 notebook at a time. It does not permit the second connection. Therefore, the limit changes time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Menu "Runtime" > "Manage Sessions", you should see a list of active sessions. Terminate those you don't need. Although you think you are opening only 2 notebooks, some previous sessions may still linger around if you just close the browser tab.

Note: However, when I hit the problem today, I did the above to check, and I have only 1 other session. Usually, I am able to run up to 3 separate sessions. I am not sure if google is dynamically adjusting this based on overall demand. I also suspect ever since they introduce the Pro, priorities may be given to subscribers.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure but may be collab provides services to a account one at a time..